# Vanilla JS version of jQuery Slidedown on Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a simpler way to add the jQuery slidedown effect in Vanilla Javascript. This is particularly difficult because it's in a dropdown menu.

Currently the js I have in place applies a class of active to the li onclick. I'm obviously able to show and hide the content, but the only thing that is missing is the slideDown effect.

I've tried doing this with CSS but can't seem to do it without declaring a fixed height.

Also, if you are going to attach code, please use jsfiddle as jsbin is locked on my machine.

Here is the markup:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="main-menu-li_dropdown">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li_dropdown">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li_dropdown">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li_dropdown">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li_dropdown">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

UPDATE: 
Here is the CSS that is being applied to the dropdown .sub-nav class when the li above it has the .active class applied to it through JS

```
        .sub-nav {
            max-height: 0;
            position: static;
            -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
            -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
            -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
            transition: all 500ms linear;
        }


.main-menu-li_dropdown.active .sub-nav {
            position: static;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height */

            transition: max-height 500ms linear;
        }
```

Comment: Look at `fade out` example on [oficial site](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: Might be interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/74934316/2311074

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you can try

```css
.slider {
 overflow-y: hidden;
 max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height */

 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: .5s;
}

.slider.closed {
 max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div class="slider" id="slider">
   <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('slider').classList.toggle('closed');">Toggle slider</button>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvfam96k/) Link

Comment: The solution must not rely on a fixed height.

Comment: @wgallop the solution does not relies on fixed height. solution uses a max-height property which means it describes an upper cap for the height. height can be anything between 0 and max-height value.as you can see the comment also its mentioned approximate max height.

Comment: Understood. This didn't work for me, however I'm posting more details about my problem.

Comment: @wgallop can you create a the demo of your code in fiddle so that its easy to try out solutions with your requirements.

Comment: When I plug it in to jsfiddle it seems to work...for some reason on my local it doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/f4sups88/2/

Comment: it works for a slide down. but beware: the transition time is always the time it requires to transition max-height to it'ŝ max value. if your element is way less high, the animation will appear much more fast! worse it gets, when using it for an accordion style slideUp/Down: the up will seem to start later... otherwise, didnt find any vanilla/css only slide snippets!

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer for scroll up/down with CSS only:

/*  Hidden */

```
#element {
    transition : 180ms transform ease-out;
    transform  : translateY(-100%);         
}
```

/* Displayed */

```
#element.displayed {
    transform  : translateY(0);
    transition : 150 transform ease-in;
}
```

NOTE: This is best suited for situations where the size of the element doesn't affect the size of other elements.
For example: a vertical submenu.