# Why is this slideUp function not smooth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a vanilla JS version of the jQuery `slideUp()`and `slideDown()` function.

My idea was to use CSS `transition` for the `height` property together with incrementing/decrementing the height using `requestAnimationFrame()`.

I tried it with the following code, and `slideDown` is working as expected, but `slideUp` is not smoothly collapsing, instead, it is just suddenly gone.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc1r742h/5/).

```js
  function toggleSlide(element) {
  // Check if the element is currently visible
  if (element.style.display== '' || element.style.display== 'none') {
    // If the element is not visible, slide it down
    slideDown(element);
  } else {
    // If the element is visible, slide it up
    slideUp(element);
  }
}


function slideDown(element) {

  // If the element is not visible, set the display and height properties
  if (element.style.display !== 'block') {
    element.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.height = 0;
  }
  
    // Get the height of the element's content
  const contentHeight = element.scrollHeight;

  // Set a variable to keep track of the element's height
  let currentHeight = 0;

  // Start an animation loop
  function animate() {
    // Increase the element's height by 10px
    currentHeight += 10;

    // Update the element's height
    element.style.height = `${currentHeight}px`;

    // If the element's height is less than the content height, request another animation frame
    if (currentHeight < contentHeight) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  // Start the animation
  animate();
}

function slideUp(element) {
  // Get the height of the element's content
  const contentHeight = element.scrollHeight;
  // Set a variable to keep track of the element's height
  let currentHeight = contentHeight;

  // Start an animation loop
  function animate() {
    // Decrease the element's height by 10px
    currentHeight -= 10;

    // Update the element's height
    element.style.height = `${currentHeight}px`;
    
    // If the element's height is greater than 0, request another animation frame
    if (currentHeight > 0) {
   
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
      // If the animation is complete, hide the element
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
  }

  // Start the animation
  animate();
}
```

```css
 .my-element {
        background-color: #ddd;
        
        transition: height 0.5s;
        overflow: hidden;
        display:none;
      }
```

```html
   <button onclick="toggleSlide(document.querySelector('.my-element'))">Slide Down</button>

    <!-- Create the element that we will slide down -->
    <div class="my-element">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et tellus in quam convallis dictum. Maecenas eget odio eget arcu accumsan porttitor. Ut elementum volutpat orci, sed tincidunt ipsum dictum at. Maecenas auctor tempus diam quis gravida. Aliquam at ultricies leo. Etiam euismod, nisi ac blandit placerat, diam turpis vestibulum diam, at ultricies turpis orci at elit. Mauris auctor dictum dolor, quis pretium nisi ultricies in. Aenean sollicitudin, quam non euismod porta, enim nisl laoreet velit, vel venenatis dui dui vel lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec et elit ut ipsum elementum volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent a nisi at est eleifend ullamcorper. Aenean porta, erat ac sagittis fermentum, leo magna tincidunt lectus, ac semper risus est et diam. Suspendisse auctor ipsum quam, id porta dui dictum sed. Vivamus ac diam non elit placerat iaculis vel at velit. Aliquam vel tincidunt velit. Duis imperdiet, dolor eu placerat luctus, ipsum quam laoreet dui, non suscipit nulla tellus et arcu. Donec dictum, massa non bibendum varius, leo urna condimentum diam, nec suscipit elit turpis vel turpis. Aenean ac nunc quis nisl tempus tincidunt a eu metus.</p>
    </div>
```

Why is `slideUp` not collapsing smoothly?

Comment: Any reason you're not using CSS transitions?

Comment: @Barmar I am using CSS transitions. The `my-element` class has `transition: height 0.5s` as a property.

Comment: I suggest you use css transition from max-height: 0 to a very large number and use only javascript to toggle the class that sets that max-height

Comment: But you also have `requestAnimationFrame()`. One or the other.

Comment: @Barmar actually my first attempt was to just use `transition: height 0.5s` and change the height between `0` and `auto`. The effect was that no animation was happening at all. It was just jumping between those states, so I thought `requestAnimationFrame()` was necessary. Any hints how to do this with the CSS transition property?

Comment: @Barmar think I found the solution at https://jsfiddle.net/gebpjo1L/18/ which avoids to use `requestAnimnationFrame()` but one has to make a single call to `setIntval`.. Probably to trigger the height change?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS Transition is the one taking effect before the toggle animation ends. Removing it solves the issue since your functions are taking care of the animating durations

```js
function toggleSlide(element) {
  // Check if the element is currently visible
  if (element.style.display== '' || element.style.display== 'none') {
    // If the element is not visible, slide it down
    slideDown(element);
  } else {
    // If the element is visible, slide it up
    slideUp(element);
  }
}


function slideDown(element) {

  // If the element is not visible, set the display and height properties
  if (element.style.display !== 'block') {
    element.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.height = 0;
  }
  
    // Get the height of the element's content
  const contentHeight = element.scrollHeight;

  // Set a variable to keep track of the element's height
  let currentHeight = 0;

  // Start an animation loop
  function animate() {
    // Increase the element's height by 10px
    currentHeight += 10;

    // Update the element's height
    element.style.height = `${currentHeight}px`;

    // If the element's height is less than the content height, request another animation frame
    if (currentHeight < contentHeight) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  // Start the animation
  animate();
}

function slideUp(element) {
  // Get the height of the element's content
  const contentHeight = element.scrollHeight;
  // Set a variable to keep track of the element's height
  let currentHeight = contentHeight;

  // Start an animation loop
  function animate() {
    // Decrease the element's height by 10px
    currentHeight -= 10;

    // Update the element's height
    element.style.height = `${currentHeight}px`;
    
    // If the element's height is greater than 0, request another animation frame
    if (currentHeight > 0) {
   
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
      // If the animation is complete, hide the element
      element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
  }

  // Start the animation
  animate();
}
```

```css
.my-element {
        background-color: #ddd;
        /* Remove the transition */
        overflow: hidden;
        display:none;
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleSlide(document.querySelector('.my-element'))">Slide Down</button>

    <!-- Create the element that we will slide down -->
    <div class="my-element">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et tellus in quam convallis dictum. Maecenas eget odio eget arcu accumsan porttitor. Ut elementum volutpat orci, sed tincidunt ipsum dictum at. Maecenas auctor tempus diam quis gravida. Aliquam at ultricies leo. Etiam euismod, nisi ac blandit placerat, diam turpis vestibulum diam, at ultricies turpis orci at elit. Mauris auctor dictum dolor, quis pretium nisi ultricies in. Aenean sollicitudin, quam non euismod porta, enim nisl laoreet velit, vel venenatis dui dui vel lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec et elit ut ipsum elementum volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent a nisi at est eleifend ullamcorper. Aenean porta, erat ac sagittis fermentum, leo magna tincidunt lectus, ac semper risus est et diam. Suspendisse auctor ipsum quam, id porta dui dictum sed. Vivamus ac diam non elit placerat iaculis vel at velit. Aliquam vel tincidunt velit. Duis imperdiet, dolor eu placerat luctus, ipsum quam laoreet dui, non suscipit nulla tellus et arcu. Donec dictum, massa non bibendum varius, leo urna condimentum diam, nec suscipit elit turpis vel turpis. Aenean ac nunc quis nisl tempus tincidunt a eu metus.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar stated, one should either use `requestAnimationFrame()` or CSS transitions. Cypherjac represents the solution of just using `requestAnimationFrame()` here comes the alternative CSS transitions solution:

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teudnr7b/4/) or

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const container = document.querySelector('div');
    const active = container.style.height !== '' && container.style.height !== '0px';
            
    if(active){
        container.style.height = "0px"
      container.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
          container.style.display = 'none';
      }, {once: true})
      return;
    }
      
    container.style.display = 'block';
    container.style.height = "auto"
    const height = container.clientHeight + "px"
    container.style.height = "0px"
     
    setTimeout(() => {
        container.style.height = height          
    }, 0) 
    
})
```

```css
.box {
    transition: height .5s ease;
    overflow  : hidden;
    height:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. I'm an unknown content height element. 
</div>
<button>Slide Toggle</button>
```

The part with setting `display` to `none`/`block` could be omitted. Only added, as I assume for most scenarios, its useful to have it completly removed from flow when toggled.

The `addEventListener:transitioned` is necessary, so the display is set after the height has been changed to 0 and CSS transition has taken place.

The `setTimeout` is necessary, because otherwise, the height would be directly set to `height` and CSS would not get the change to animate.